# How to detect that raycast isn't hitting object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project (VR, so I don't use mouse) I need to highlight or change color of multiple object with tag but one object at once and I can't figure out how to detect that raycast is no longer hitting object.
Here's my code now:

```
public class colorChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    private bool isSelected = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hitInfo, 10))
        {
            if (hitInfo.transform.tag == "changeToColor")
            {
                isSelected = true;
                hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255);
            }
            else
            {
                isSelected = false;
            }
        }
      /*  if(isSelected == false)
        {
            hitInfo.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 255);
        } */
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFW3P.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the object that is being hit so that when the raycast hits a new object you change back the color for the previous object the raycast hit and then change the saved object to the new.

Like this:

```cs
private Renderer m_HitObject;
private Color m_HitObjectOldColor;

...

if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hitInfo, 10))
{

    Renderer hitRenderer = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if(hitInfo.transform.CompareTag("changeToColor"))
    {
         if(m_HitObject != null && hitRenderer != 
            m_HitObject)
           {
             m_HitObject.color = m_OldColor;
           }

         m_HitObject = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
         m_OldColor = hitRenderer.material.color;

         hitRenderer.material.color = new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255);
    }
}
```

Sorry for any spelling mistakes luckily your IDE will fix that.

Comment: You should probably rather store the `Renderer` reference as well so you don't need to get it repeatedly

Comment: Good point that would safe a lot of performance. and typing let me edit that real quick.